# How to make session serialize the object like php session data?

Tags: node.js

For example want to convert the object to session serialized data on node js,

INPUT :

`{ Status: 'Success', Token: '59c272ec37b74' },`

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

`'Status|s:7:"Success";Token|s:13:"59c272ec37b74"'`

If any `npm` package available share it, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stringify javascript objects instead of serializing , but since that is out of scope of this question , you can use [serialize javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript). Or you can use [node serialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-serialize)

Comment: refer this link, need reverse process of this function https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-unserialize#unserializesessionstring